# Constructing dynamic columns from parameters in Sybase

Tags: sap-ase

I'm trying to write a stored proc (SP) in Sybase.

The SP takes 5 varchar parameters.

Based on the parameters passed, I want to construct the column names to be selected from a particular table.

The below works:

**DECLARE @TEST VARCHAR(50)
            SELECT @TEST = "country"
            --print @TEST**

**execute("SELECT DISTINCT id_country AS id_level, Country AS nm_level
FROM tempdb..tbl_books INNER JOIN 
(tbl_ch2_bespoke_report INNER JOIN tbl_ch2_bespoke_rpt_mapping 
ON tbl_ch2_bespoke_report.id_report = tbl_ch2_bespoke_rpt_mapping.id_report)
ON id_" + @TEST + "= tbl_ch2_bespoke_rpt_mapping.id_pnl_level
WHERE tbl_ch2_bespoke_report.id_report = 14")**

but gives me multiple results:

1   1 row(s) affected.

```
id_level    nm_level
```

1   4376    XYZ
2   4340    ABC

I would like to however **only** obtain the 2nd result.

Do I need to necessarily use **dynamic SQL** to achieve this?

Many thanks for your help.

--Chapax

Comment: What is actually returned as I think there is only one set of data returned. The 1 row(s) affected is not actually retuned to the calling code

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'd like to eliminate the "1 row(s) affected." line. If so, the "set nocount on/off" option should do the trick:

```
declare @something int
declare @query varchar(2000)
set nocount  on
select @something=30
select @query = "SELECT * FROM a_table where id_row = " + convert(varchar(10),@something) 
set nocount  off
exec (@query)
```

or

```
declare @something int
declare @query varchar(2000)
set nocount  on
select @something=30
set nocount  off
SELECT * FROM a_table where id_row = @something
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `SET NOCOUNT {ON|OFF}` to turn off row count messages.
2. Yes, you need to you dynamic SQL to change the structure or content of the result set (either the column list or the `WHERE` clause).